# How to show a bifurcation occurs in the following dynamic problem

Tags: dynamical-systems, bifurcation

I have the following non-dimensional model:

$\dot{u}=u(1-u)-X\frac{u}{\alpha+u}$

Now, assuming $\alpha>1$ and $X>0$ are constants, I want to show a bifurcation happens locally near the zero state when $X=\alpha$. I have tried setting the equation equal to zero to see if the equilibrium states change, but I dont seem to get anywehre with it. I was also thinking of maybe using taylor expansion of the denominator of the fractional term, but also havent gotten far using that. Any ideas how this can be shown?

Thanks

Comment: Hint. For $1$D systems, a bifurcation occurs when the derivative of $\dot{u}$ with respect to $u$ evaluated in a steady state (or equilibrium) changes sign as $X$ and $\alpha$ vary...

Comment: Ah, yeah, thanks for that! As an aside, what would a bifurcation like this (i.e. when X<a unstable, X>a stable) be called?

Comment: I guess there are two steady states exchanging their stability. If it is the case, then we hava a transcritical bifurcation.